# adobe font usage past subscription

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, creative-cloud, typekit

*Example to explain above question:*

If my company sells a product to a client that includes a font found and used through fonts.adobe.com and the creative cloud subscription,

**would they still be usable**, if used on a website, **after cancelling the creative cloud  at some point?**

**Would it still be legal to use them? (no redesign, just our customer keeping to use the product we provided him back when our company had the creative cloud subscription)**

Comment: or can you buy a permanent font license from adobe fonts? (because i have never seen a way to do so)

Comment: I think this is a question for Adobe since they control the subscription. I mean ... you **can't** use other software if the subscription is over and they no longer offer a perpetual license for anything else. (renting software is just horrible for consumers/workers and only benefits Adobe).

Comment: If you’re using the fonts directly from Adobe Fonts (via a `use.typekit.com` style sheet), then no – that style sheet will lead to a 404 once the subscription expires, and the fonts will not load. Even if you downloaded and copied the fonts, that in itself would be against the EULA. ‘Legal’ is a fuzzy term; your EULA is what matters here.

Comment: Fonts have even been removed from Adobe fonts causing all working documents using those fonts to break. I still use them myself but it comes with a risk. If it's for an important job I would have to buy the font in that case.

Comment: ok, thank you, that's what i thought. Yeah, i should definitely ask Adobe directly. Btw: Has anyone ever found an Adobe Font or Typekit Font anywhere else to buy? Because to me it seemed so far, their fonts were site-exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to, you can buy the fonts directly from the mentioned providers, see this:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/font-licensing.html#act-lic